# Is there any significance to using tee?

Tags: command-line, tee

Why is it that almost all instructions regarding appending text to system files like `fstab` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<name>.list` involve using `tee` ***and*** `echo` to append said text?

Take the following examples, which are run *as root*:

```bash
## 1
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee -a file1
## 2
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' >> file2
```

Running `diff -u file1 file2` returns nothing; running `md5sum file1 file2` shows their checksums are identical, which brings me back to my original question:

Why is the `| tee <FILENAME>` so prevalent across Ubuntu docs, is it just good practice, otherwise wouldn't it be easier to just use example 2 instead of passing the output from `echo` to `tee`?

Comment: You are missing sudo in your commands; that will show different results between the 2 ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm running these commands as root.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is a difference: tee duplicates the output: it sends it both to the file and to the display.

But there is more:

- For example, if you want to write some string into two files at once, the command with tee you can use is:

  ```
   echo "some text" | tee file1 > file2
  ```
- Another thing tee can help you is to avoid one problem when using sudo. The normal output redirection operator is always executed with your user privileges, also when you write a sudo in front of the command which generates the STDOUT text. In other words, this will fail if you dont have the permission to write to that file:

  ```
   sudo echo "something" > bar
  ```

  But with tee, everything will go well:

  ```
  echo "something" | sudo tee bar
  ```

2 examples from [this site](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/05/how-to-use-tee-command.html). It has some more.

Comment: You can `sudo` without `tee` - `sudo sh -c 'echo SOMETHING > FILE'`... ;)

Comment: @wilf yeah, but when you need to output quotes `"`, things becomes messy

Comment: In the first case, if you want to write to N files, I would prefer `echo "some text" | tee file1 file2 ... fileN` and maybe append `> /dev/null`, if you don't want clutter on stdout.

Comment: Nice one @ElmarZander :)

Comment: link seems broken (2 examples from this site. It has some more.)
Success! The test.com virtual host is working!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tee-command-linux-example/

but mostly thanks, idk tee existed a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 32):

`tee` takes the standard input stream and writes it to *both* the standard output stream as well as a file stream. If it helps people remember, the command name comes from a T-splitter in plumbing.  There is a nice [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) where I learned about the origin of the command name.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice that you provided etymology of tee

Answer (score 17):

First of all, `tee` itself doesn't append text, nor does `>`.

It is `tee -a` and its complement, `>>` that APPENDS text.

I don't believe all shells support the `>>` function, so that is why `tee` is more commonly used. (Think of just plain old `sh`). Tee is a command, while `>>` is an operator.

If you use (my personal favorite) `bash`, `>` and `>>` are much nicer/easier.

Using `tee` also allows you to sudo JUST that command so you don't have to sudo the entire statement, as in `sudo sh -c "echo foo > bar"`. `tee` also allows you to split the output. Of course, all of this can be seen in `man tee`. It's mainly just your personal preference.

For further reading, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538834/whats-the-difference-between-echo-x-y-and-echo-x-tee-y) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20469/difference-between-21-output-log-and-21-tee-output-log).

Comment: Clarification on "sudo JUST that command", for anyone finding this a little complex: using a form like `sudo somecommand >> filea` will run `sudo somecommand` and then, as the *invoking* user, append the output to `filea`.  Using `sudo sh -c "somecommand >> filea"` works, but can cause nested-quoting nightmares.  Using `somecommand | sudo tee -a filea` runs `somecommand` as the invoking user, and then appends the output to `filea` as root - which is usually what the user wanted.

Comment: @Darael I edited the post. Thank you for making the clarification.